# Cubism d3 dependency with requirejs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, requirejs, cubism.js

I am having difficulty declaring the cubism's dependency on d3, when using require.js.

Config is as:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: './',
  paths: {
    'jquery': './jquery-1.10.2.min',
    'd3': './d3.min',
    'cubism': './cubism.v1'
 },
 shim: {
    cubism: {
        deps: ['d3']
    }
 }
});
```

The error I am getting is:

```
cubism.v1.js:187 Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
at cubism.v1.js:187
at cubism.v1.js:1331
```

Please help find me where I did wrong?

Comment: Are you using d3 v4? As far as I know, cubism is not compatible with v4.

Comment: @gerardo-furtado Yes. it is 4.4.1

Comment: I changed d3 to v3 and am getting different error where cubism is not loaded.

Comment: Try it out without require.js first, to see if they are compatible or check the docs.

Comment: Yes. It was working before adding require.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cubism is not loading as expected when using require.js in my case. I have a workaround to this issue where I change the requirejs config as:

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: './',
paths: {
    jquery: './jquery-1.10.2.min',
    d3: 'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min',
    cubism_v1: './cubism.v1'
},
shim: {
    cubism_v1: {
        deps: ['d3']
    }
}
});
```

And declare another module as:

```
define('cubism', ['cubism_v1'], function (cubism) {
   return this.cubism; 
});
```

Then I am able to use cubism in other places as required.

```
requirejs(['jQuery', 'd3', 'cubism'], function (jQuery, d3, cubism) {
   // cubism related code here
});
```